# JSON serialization of an object with a variable length using JsonConvert in .net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I need help with some JSON serialization using the .NET/Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject method. I have a class which I am using to store the variables that are outbound, called JSONVars.

My question is about how to handle the "Answer" variables in the below sample.

The first and last names always have one return in the loop, so that's easy. However the Answer part could have multiple returns in a loop.

A theoretical outbound JSON string would look like:

```
{ 
    "FirstName" : "John", 
    "LastName" : "Doe", 
    "FavoriteVacation" : "Beach", 
    "FavoriteState" : "FL" 
    ..... 
}
```

with the "..." representing 1 to n possible returns in the loop.

As you can see, the place that I'm sending the JSON string needs to have it all in one comma delimited string that is properly formatted JSON, so I can't send the Answer block as a JSON array, like this (it will fail):

```
{ 
    "FirstName" : "John", 
    "LastName" : "Doe", 
    "Answers" : [ 
        "FavoriteVacation" : "Beach", 
        "FavoriteState" : "FL" ..... 
}
```

How can I adjust this so that I can "add" to the json serialized string 1 to n "answer" blocks?

Here is my code:

```
 public class JSONVars
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        //??? public string Answer;
    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

  foreach (var objReturn in objlst)
            {

   JSONVars jsonvars = new JSONVars();
   jsonvars.FirstName = objReturn.FirstName;
   jsonvars.LastName = objReturn.LastName;



foreach (var answerobj in objReturn.SurveyAnswers)
                {

                    if (answerobj.Vacation != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var answerobjVaca in answerobj.Vacation)
                        {
                          //???????
                          //answerobjVaca.QuestionText;
                          //answerobjVaca.AnswerText;
                        }
                    }
                }
 var jsonHolder = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonvars);
}
}
```

The jsonHolder var is what is being sent out to an external service and needs to be properly serialized for JSON transmission.

Please note some code (like how objReturn is populated) left out for brevity.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of your `JSONVars` class if you need to dynamically add or remove properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and easy solution is to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` in place of `JSONVars`. So you do something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict["FirstName"] = objReturn.FirstName;
dict["LastName"] = objReturn.LastName;
foreach (var answerobj in objReturn.SurveyAnswers)
{
    // it's not entirely clear where you are getting the JSON
    // property names from, but assuming `QuestionText` gives you the property name
    // Otherwise, adjust as necessary...
    dict[answerObj.QuestionText] = answerObj.AnswerText;
}
```

The more complicated solution would be to write a custom converter (which isn't that hard). Then you could have your `JSONVars` class look like this:

```
public class JSONVars
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public Dictionary<string,object> Answers;
}
```

And use your custom converter to flatten `Answers` into your JSON string.

Comment: so, on the first "quick and dirty" example, once the dict object is filled with one pass through the overall loop (by that I mean FirstName + LastName + [n] Question/Answer "nodes"), can I just serialize the dictionary through JsonConvert.SerializeObject() ?

Comment: @optionsix: Yes

Answer (score 0):

you must do like this

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John", 
    "LastName" : "Doe", 
    "Answers" : [
        {
            "Question":"FavoriteVacation",
            "Answer":"Beach"
        },
        {
            "Question": "FavoriteState",
            "Answer":"FL"
        }, ... 
    ]
}
```